# First program in Python for data analysis

Tags: python, numpy, database, pandas

I'm just starting my adventure with python and I wanted to share my first project with you and ask for feedback and advice. This is a script for my friend to automate all calculations and database operations.

**What my code does:**

1. Merge together the csv files in the specified folder forming two sets.
2. Calculate the difference in days between the two date columns.
3. Filter the data over a given date range.
4. Checking that the id from the data frame L is not part of the M.
5. Creates output tables where the results will be stored.
6. Mainly calculation of the average of individual columns after preparation
7. Saving the results in a table

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os, sys
import glob
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import time

listOfFiles = []
tempDF = pd.DataFrame()
tempDF2 = pd.DataFrame()


def get_filenames():
    Tk().withdraw()
    print("Initializing Dialogue... \\nPlease select a file.")
    tk_filenames = filedialog.askdirectory()
    tempDir = tk_filenames
    return tempDir


choosen_dir = get_filenames()

os.chdir(choosen_dir)
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    listOfFiles.append(file)

for file in listOfFiles:
    if file.startswith('L'):
        Table = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')
        DF1 = pd.DataFrame(Table)
        tempDF = tempDF.append(DF1, sort=False)
    elif file.startswith('M'):
        Table2 = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')
        DF2 = pd.DataFrame(Table2)
        tempDF2 = tempDF2.append(DF2, sort=False)
    else:
        print('404')

DFL = tempDF
DFM = tempDF2


class ToDate():

    def change_to_date(self, a, b):
        a[b] = pd.to_datetime(a[b])


dat = ToDate()
dat.change_to_date(DFL, 'LDUR')
dat.change_to_date(DFL, 'LDOP')
dat.change_to_date(DFM, 'LDOP')
dat.change_to_date(DFM, 'LDUR')
DFL['M_WAGUR'] = DFL['LDOP'] - DFL['LDUR']
DFM['M_WAGUR'] = DFM['LDUR'] - DFM['LDOP']
DFL['M_WAGUR'] = DFL['M_WAGUR'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
DFM['M_WAGUR'] = DFM['M_WAGUR'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

date1 = input('Date range from YYYY-MM-DD')
date2 = input('Date range to YYYY-MM-DD')

DFL = DFL[(DFL['LDOP'] >= date1) & (DFL['LDOP'] <= date2)]
DFM = DFM[(DFM['LDUR'] >= date1) & (DFM['LDUR'] <= date2)]

DFM_BL = DFM
ListL = DFL.ID1.tolist()
DFM_BL = DFM_BL[~DFM_BL.ID1.isin(ListL)]

def createDT(name):
    temp = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Race','number of individuals','littering         youngsters',
                               'first litter.','more than first litter',
                               'amount_21','lose_21','nip_count',
                               'age','between_litter'],index =[1])
    temp['Race'] = name
    return temp

def sortedDT(DT, col, number):
    newDT = DT[DT[col] == number]
    return newDT

def months(DT, col, col2):
    newDT = DT[DT[col] != DT[col2]]
    return newDT


def birth(DFL, DFM):
    if len(DFL) > 0:
        pigs = DFL[['LIL11', 'LIL21']]
        pigs2 = DFM[['LIL11', 'LIL21']]
        pigs = pigs.append(pigs2)
        pigs['loses'] = pigs['LIL11'] - pigs['LIL21']
        pigs['ST21'] = (pigs['loses'] / pigs['LIL11']) * 100
        return pigs
    else:
        pigs = DFM[['LIL11', 'LIL21']]
        pigs['loses'] = pigs['LIL11'] - pigs['LIL21']
        pigs['ST21'] = (pigs['loses'] / pigs['LIL11']) * 100
        return pigs


def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n.all():
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s


def all_count(DFL, DFM, DFM_BL, n, new):
    if len(DFL) > 0:
        s = sum_digits(n)
        pigs = birth(DFL, DFM)
        DFM_BL = DFM_BL.drop_duplicates(subset='ID1', keep="first").copy()
        new['first litter'] = len(DFL)
        new['more than first litter'] = len(DFL) + len(DFM)
        new['number of individuals'] = len(DFL) + len(DFM_BL)
        new['littering youngsters'] = np.around(pigs['LIL11'].mean(), decimals=2)
        new['amount_21'] = np.around(pigs['LIL21'].mean(), decimals=2)
        new['lose_21'] = np.around(pigs['ST21'].mean(), decimals=2)
        new['age'] = np.around(DFL['M_WAGUR'].mean())
        new['between_litter'] = np.around(DFM['M_WAGUR'].mean())
        new['nip_count'] = np.around(s.mean(), decimals=2)

        return new

    else:
        pigs = birth(DFL, DFM)
        dfm = DFM.drop_duplicates(subset='LPROS1', keep="first").copy()
        new['first litter'] = "-"
        new['more than first litter'] = len(DFM)
        new['number of individuals'] = len(dfm)
        new['littering youngsters'] = np.around(pigs['LIL11'].mean(), decimals=2)
        new['amount_21'] = np.around(pigs['LIL21'].mean(), decimals=2)
        new['lose_21'] = np.around(pigs['ST21'].mean(), decimals=2)
        new['age'] = "-"
        new['between_litter'] = np.around(DFM['M_WAGUR'].mean())
        new['nip_count'] = "-"

        return new

W1R43 = createDT('W1R43')
L_W1R43 = sortedDT(DFL,'ID1',10).copy()
M_W1R43 = sortedDT(DFM,'ID1',10).copy()
BL_W1R43 = sortedDT(DFM_BL,'ID1',10).copy()
all_count(L_W1R43,MW1R43,BL_W1R43,W1R43['LSUT1'],W1R43)

last = pd.concat([W1R43, ... ])
last.to_csv('Results.txt', header=True, index=False, sep='\t', mode='w')
last.to_html('Results.html',index=False)
```

In the future, I would like to transfer this code to Django as one of the tools.

Please advise me what I should change, what I should avoid and if there is something correct in this code you can also let me know.

Comment: I would begin to use MVP since you want to use Django. Separate the view from the logic. You have several functions spread in the code together with dataframes definitions etc. Put them into classes (one specifically for the view, Tkinter in this case). Another for callbacks (you use tkinter and CLI at the same time, use callbacks to return values to the user via Tkinter, CLI, Django etc.). Also use `if __name__ == '__main__':` and a `main()` so it's easier to know where we should begin to read your code. If you need help, just ping.

Comment: @Raphael Please post answers in the answer boxes.

Comment: @Peilonrayz This is far from be an answer in my opinion, just some tips.

Comment: @Raphael, I agree with Peilonrayz.  I think that you should take your comment and make it into a review, it sounds like you have some good information there, why not get some recognition for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the issues I've found with your code. But there are
many more left and it is very hard to review your code without seeing
some sample data files. Consider rewriting your code, taking these
suggestions into account and then posting another request for code
review.

#### Avoid mixing import styles

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os, sys
import glob
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import time
```

It is ugly and can be confusing to mix import styles. Choose the one
you like, either `from foo import bar` or `import foo [as bar]`, and
stick with that as much as possible.

#### Wrap code in `main`

Writing code at the module level means that the global namespace is
modified when the code runs. Suppose you have the following code:

```
y = ...
...
for i in range(x):
    ...
for i in range(y):
    ...
```

You decide to refactor the second for-loop into its own function, but
you forget to pass `y` as a parameter:

```
def new_fun():
    for i in range(y):
        ...
y = ...
...
for i in range(x):
    ...
new_fun()
```

The code contains a bug but still runs. It can cause nasty and hard to
debug bugs (has happened to me several times before I wised
up). Therefore, it's good practice to always wrap the main code in a
`main`, even for small scripts. Like this:

```
def main():
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Follow PEP 8

Follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - Python's
style guide. So use snake-case instead of camel-case for variable
names. E.g `list_of_files` instead of `listOfFiles`.

#### Naming

Ensure that names are accurate, understandable and follows PEP 8. E.g

```
choosen_dir = get_filenames()
os.chdir(choosen_dir)
```

The function gets a *directory* not filenames, so it should be called
`get_dir`.

The name `file` should be avoided because it clashes with a
Python builtin. I'd replace it with `fname`.

Also names such as `W1R43`, `L_W1R43` and `ListL` are very cryptic. I
have looked at the code for a while but I still have no idea what they
are about.

#### Intermediate lists

You have code like

```
listOfFiles = []
...
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    listOfFiles.append(file)
for file in listOfFiles:
    ...
```

Instead you can just write

```
for file in glob.glob("*.csv")
```

without creating the `listOfFiles` list.

#### ToDate

I don't understand the purpose of this class. I think you can just write:

```
df_l['LDUR'] = pd.to_datetime(df_l['LDUR'])
df_l['LDOP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_l['LDOP'])
df_m['LDUR'] = pd.to_datetime(df_m['LDUR'])
df_m['LDOP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_m['LDOP'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is change the

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
```

to

```py
import tkinter as tk
```

It is generally seen as bad form to 'pollute' the namespace by doing `from tkinter import *`, see the last paragraph in [PEP 8's section on imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). By using `import tkinter as tk` and referencing everything as e.g. `tk.filedialog` it stays clear where the function came from.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Would you please explain your reasoning a little bit, add some meat to your answer?